# throws an exception in prepared statement in executeUpdate

Tags: java, sql

```
MySQLdb mySQLdb =new MySQLdb();
    query="INSERT  INTO user(username,password,firstname,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    System.out.println(user.getUsername()+"  "+user.getPassword()+" "+user.getName()+" "+user.getEmail());
    connection= mySQLdb.getConnection();
    try {

        preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate(query);//--->throws exception here
        //System.out.println("101");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //System.out.println("102");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Errormessage:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1
java.sql.SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1571)
```

help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not pass the query string in `executeUpdate()`
It will solve your issue
because when you pass the parameter it calls the Statement's `executeUpdate()` function 
(ie) `statement.excuteUpdate(Query);`

For PreparedStatement--->  `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 3):

Call `executeUpdate` without parameter:

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2):

Already you have set a query parameter at

```
preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                                                ^Here
```

So instead calling this

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate(query);
```

Remove the query parameter in `executeUpdate();`

And make it as

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```